# Astra hatchback is boiling while driven short distance it boiling hot. Have taken out the thermostat but still no solution

Tags: coolant

Opel Astra water thank is boiling while driven short distance...taking lot of water in it...Have removed thermostat but still no solution...what might be a problem pls help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

As a first step, I recommend that you check the actual temperature of the coolant with a thermometer.  It may appear to be boiling due to air being injected into the system but not actually boiling.

That being said, you should check the following:

1. Cooling system for correct coolant level and purging.
2. Radiator for correct flow of both coolant and air.
3. Radiator fan for proper operation.
4. Coolant hoses for proper connection and condition.
5. Water pump for proper operation.

Once you have eliminated all those as potential causes, another possibility is that you have a blown head gasket that is allowing combustion gasses to enter the cooling system where they bubble up in the overflow tank.  This condition can also quickly overheat the coolant because those gases are very hot.

Generally you will see oily residue in the coolant and/or smell exhaust gasses in the vapors coming out of the overflow tank.

Comment: As a first step ... *put the thermostat back in!*

Comment: Either test the thermostat first, or put a new one in to make sure it is not adding to the issue.